# Use a Wifi AP as a reciever?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a Cisco WAP-200 WI-FI access point which i want to hook up to my desktop and act as a WI-FI receiver.

is it possible with any kind of mod or custom firmware for the access point?

Comment: Thank you for asking; unfortunately this question seems to be about home / consumer networking.  Both home networking and consumer class devices are [off-topic here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask/).  [su] is the right place to ask this question;  rest assured that several of our members answer there too.

Answer (score 0):

That's a "Cisco Small Business" (aka *Linksys*) device. It is not designed to be a wireless "station"; as such, it lacks the ability to associate with an access point.  What you want is the "WET" (wireless bridge), or any number of "gaming adapters" on the market.

(And USB wifi adapters -- smaller than a dime -- can be found for pocket change.)

Comment: Actually you may be able to achieve this using [bridge mode](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=9d193b95ac3b4740a9deda93bb20af8b_Configuration_of_AP_Wireless_Bridge_Mode_on_WAP200E_Wireless.xml&pid=2&converted=0).

Comment: The bridge requires WDS on the other end. He probably wants a repeater.